# What is this gun that wipes everything out?

Tags: borderlands, xbox-360

I played online for the first time over the weekend, and I saw a guy using some sort of gun that wiped absolutely everything out. *Everything!* He even killed the Rakk Hive after about 5 shots!

**What on earth was that gun?**

Comment: Most of this information isn't necessary as part of your question.  Maybe you should remove everything but the info on the gun you're trying to identify.

Comment: Fair point, but I also appreciate people's opinions on online gaming - and seeing as that would be subjective on it's own then I expect it would be closed for being argumentative. A cacth 22. Anyway the response below by Quantumgeek is useful.

Comment: There are plenty of places for you to express your opinions on online gaming. This is the place where you can ask questions.

Comment: @Mike Ultimately, this is a Q and A site, not a forum for opinions. While your discussion topics are interesting, this isn't the place for them. Here, they only serve to dilute the question itself.

Comment: I removed the portions of the question relating to how people behave online. We aren't a discussion forum and there's no benefit to having that information there. It detracts from actually getting real answers. However, I have left the shield in because while the gun is the main portion of the question, it happens that the shield is related. The subjectivity in addressing the gun and shield aren't to the degree of detracting from the Q&A material, I don't think, because the meat of the question is very direct. [Related Meta discussion here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/)

Comment: Really, I want to insert the shield portion in the question body, too. It helps the context of the answer, as it's basically both about modded items. But I'm not sure how I want to phrase it.

Comment: Fair enough. Noted.

Comment: The shield was a mod, probably the gun too, but the shields are more common: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73634/where-can-i-find-more-omega-equipment/80470#80470

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He was most likely using a modded gun. I generally play with a group of people I know, but if I ever go on xbox live with randoms, it seems like they always have modded weapons and shields.

Comment: What's modded? And how is it done? Newbie to nline gaming so I've only played the way it's come in the box.

Comment: Just found out about modded. Shame that. But if it rocks their boat to be invincible.

Comment: There isn't even any mention of the shield now.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Thanks. I removed that part of my answer since it doesn't really make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The user was most likely using a "hacked weapon". These items have a habit of showing up in public online play.

A hacked weapon is effectivley a player-made item cheated into the game to give the player an unfair advantage. Once you know how to modifier the game to allow your own weapons, it is easy to allow for bonuses like 10000x experience gain, or 999x damage multiplier.

It makes the game a cakewalk, but can often ruin the fun, especially for honest players trying to play alongside the "hacked" player. The best thing you can do is play with people you know, or friend players you know you can trust.