# Where can I find more "Omega" equipment?

Tags: borderlands

In a recent multiplayer game, one of my teammates dropped an odd shield the likes of which I'd never seen.  They stood there and kept shooting at it for awhile, so I presumed they meant for me to pick it up.  The shield card stats are below:

- Name:  Ironclad Omega
- Manufacturer:  Pangolin
- Rarity:  Pearlescent
- Capacity:  214748
- Recharge Delay:  10
- Flavor Text:  I stand unvanquished!  The Alpha and that other thing.
- Value:  $9,999,999

When I equip the shield, however, my shield's maximum charge doesn't match the card's stats - it tops out at 2147483647!  Additionally, it seems the shield never *actually* depletes - no matter how many hits I take, it stays maxed.  I'm effectively invincible!

In the same multiplayer game, I noticed one team member (not sure if it was the same) was an "Omega" class.  So, this got me to thinking there might be more "Omega" type equipment to find.

Is there more equipment like this (weapons, grenade mods, COMs)?  Or did I just pick up someone's hacked shield?  If there is more, where and how can I find it?

Comment: Check [the wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Omega) no such thing as an Omega brand or any such guns. Mr. November's correct.

Comment: @BenBrocka there isn't an Omega brand, but it is the name of a specific shield, see my answer below...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is most definitely a hacked shield. The reason it caps at that number is because the value is stored as a 32 bit integer, which has a maximum value of 2147483647.

Furthermore, exercise extreme caution when picking up items from strangers. There are certain ways to hack an item that will corrupt the save of someone who picks it up.

Comment: Maaan people ruin everything :(

Comment: Wait, how do they manage to safely store an item that corrupts its owner's inventory? Sounds like an old gamer's tale.

Comment: @kotekzot It wipes your inventory (and anything you have in the bank) to become the only thing you're carrying. I suspect the hackers aren't 'safely storing' anything, they're probably not able to carry anything else either.

Comment: @Keith I see, thanks for the explanation. Guess that's what mules are for.

Comment: If they're hacking they don't need to carry it.  It can just be generated out of thin air.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this recently - in a multiplayer game a level 64 player dropped a pile of 'Omega Shock' shields.

Without really thinking I picked one up, and now it's the only thing I can have in my inventory, and it's pretty much ruined my save-game with no way to revert it.

It also wiped out the bank at Moxxie's Underdome.

So I second Mr November - be extremely careful picking any of this hacked junk up.

However, there is real 'Omega' gear in game - the [Atlas Omega shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Atlas_Omega):

[image: Atlas Omega]

There is also an [Ironclad shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ironclad):

[image: Pangolin Ironclad]

My guess would be that these two items were merged together in some kind of hack to get the shields we've both seen.

I've seen forum posts claiming that this is a [glitched Crawmerax drop](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Best_Shield_Ever%3F):

[image: Ironclad Omega]

However, if that were legitimate it would make such items incredibly rare - the goon who I met in MP was dropping piles of them.

Comment: Max level is 69, by the way

Comment: @JohnoBoy cheers