# Unlimited orange omega shield?

Tags: borderlands

I found an Omega Shield, it has no limit and a guy dropped it on multiplayer. It's a Tiadore and all I hear is an Atlas Omega Shield. It says Alpha and that other thing. I can keep all my items and any level can use it.

Is it hacked?

Comment: Sounds similar to the Omega shield found on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73634/where-can-i-find-more-omega-equipment), which was hacked. Can you edit your question to list the stats?

Comment: I haven't played the first Borderlands in about a year. However, if you're saying that it's not the [Atlas Omega](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Atlas_Omega), it sounds like it might be a modded/hacked shield. There's nothing that I can find or recall that has the word "Omega" in it in the first game.

Comment: Well, that sound's like a hacked item to me.

Comment: Most likely hacked. The Omega shield is one of the three pearlescent shields introduced in the Secter Armory of General Knoxx, and it is manufactured by Atlas. Having no limit should be fishy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a hacked item.

Some people hack/mod different weapons, so they become overpowered.
They can choose any stats for them, and since it doesn't really require any special file, everyone can get them.

If a "hacker" mods a weapon, that he use in multiplayer and then drops it, you'll be able to pick it up and use it yourself.

Since I don't recall any shield with that name, yes, I would call it an hacked item.